# Search for sequences in multiple vectors

Tags: regex, r

What is the easiest way to find the sequence I need in multiple vectors in R without using loops?
For example, I need to find vectors their "yahoo" comes after "google"(only order matters).

```
seq = c("google","yahoo")
```

Matches:

```
vec1 = c("smth","google","smth","yahoo","smth")
```

Not matches:

```
vec2 = c("smth","yahoo","smth","google","smth")
```

Comment: Do you want a TRUE/FALSE output?

Comment: Try `v1 <- paste(vec1, collapse=' ');v2 <- paste(vec2, collapse=' ');grepl(paste(seq, collapse='.*'), v1)`

Comment: Yes, I need TRUE/FALSE output

Comment: Thanks. I thought, may be there is standard function which will work without converting vectors to strings.

Comment: If there is only a single instance of 'google', 'yahoo', in each vector then `which(vec1==seq[1]) < which(vec1==seq[2])` It can be made in a function `f1 <- function(vec, seq){
 which(vec==seq[1]) < which(vec==seq[2])}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use which function to find the positions of your search terms within a given vector

```
which(vec1=="google")[1] < which(vec1=="yahoo")[1]
```

use [1] if you're interested only in the first occurrence of each search term.

Answer (score 2):

Check this assuming you have unique values for yahoo and google:

```
library(dplyr)


dt = data.frame(vec1 = c("smth","google","smth","yahoo","smth"))

dt = dt %>% mutate(row = row_number()) # get the row number for each value of vec1

dt$row[dt$vec1=="google"] < dt$row[dt$vec1=="yahoo"] # returns T/F
```

Modify this if you don't have unique vec1 values. This one uses the max row number:

```
dt = data.frame(vec1 = c("smth","google","smth","yahoo","smth"))

dt = dt %>% mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(vec1) %>% summarise(row = max(row)) # get the max row number for each unique value of vec1

dt$row[dt$vec1=="google"] < dt$row[dt$vec1=="yahoo"]
```